# operational error pymssql in python. divided zero

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, divide-by-zero, nullif

I have this query in Sqlserver that works fine:

```
select  YEARWEEK_DATE as PERIODO ,banner as BANNER,ubicacion as UBICACION,branchid as BRANCHID ,marca as MARCA, 
clase as CLASE,sum(unidades_vendidas) as UNIDADES_VENDIDAS, 
sum(unidades_vendidas * PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO) as VENTA_COSTO_VALORIZADA,
sum(Venta_Neta) as VENTA_NETA ,sum(Stock) as STOCK,ROUND(sum(Stock_Valorizado),2) as VALORIZADO_STOCK, 
ROUND(sum(Stock)/sum(NULLIF (unidades_vendidas,0)),1) as ROTACION_UNIDADES , 
ROUND(sum(Venta_Neta)/ sum(NULLIF (unidades_vendidas,0) * PRECIO_COSTO_CON_DESCUENTO)/1.21,5) as MARKUP
from dabra.dbo.bi_tablero_stock_articulo_reporte tablero
where YEARMONTH_DATE 
like (select concat(CAST(year(GETDATE()) AS Varchar), right('0' + convert(varchar,datepart(mm,getdate())),2)))
and branchid <>401
and marca IS NOT NULL 
group by  marca,clase,branchid, banner, ubicacion, YEARWEEK_DATE 
ORDER BY marca
```

when I try to get the same result via python I get this error message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    MSSQLDatabaseException                    Traceback (most recent call last)
    src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.fetchall()
    
    src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.getrow()
    
    src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLRowIterator.__next__()
    
    src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.fetch_next_row()
    
    src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx in pymssql._mssql.check_cancel_and_raise()
    
    src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx in pymssql._mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException()
    
    src\pymssql\_mssql.pyx in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException()
    
    MSSQLDatabaseException: (8134, b'Divide by zero error encountered.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
    
    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
    
    OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py in fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor)
        976         try:
    --> 977             rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
        978             result._soft_close()
    
    src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.fetchall()
    
    OperationalError: (8134, b'Divide by zero error encountered.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
    ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12868/3629759782.py in <module>
    ----> 1 DF = pd.read_sql_query(sqlFile,engine)
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_sql_query(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize, dtype)
        434     """
        435     pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con)
    --> 436     return pandas_sql.read_query(
        437         sql,
        438         index_col=index_col,
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize, dtype)
       1591             )
       1592         else:
    -> 1593             data = result.fetchall()
       1594             frame = _wrap_result(
       1595                 data,
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py in fetchall(self)
        990         """A synonym for the :meth:`_engine.Result.all` method."""
        991 
    --> 992         return self._allrows()
        993 
        994     def fetchone(self):
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\result.py in _allrows(self)
        398         make_row = self._row_getter
        399 
    --> 400         rows = self._fetchall_impl()
        401         if make_row:
        402             made_rows = [make_row(row) for row in rows]
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py in _fetchall_impl(self)
       1795 
       1796     def _fetchall_impl(self):
    -> 1797         return self.cursor_strategy.fetchall(self, self.cursor)
       1798 
       1799     def _fetchmany_impl(self, size=None):
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py in fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor)
        979             return rows
        980         except BaseException as e:
    --> 981             self.handle_exception(result, dbapi_cursor, e)
        982 
        983 
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py in handle_exception(self, result, dbapi_cursor, err)
        939 
        940     def handle_exception(self, result, dbapi_cursor, err):
    --> 941         result.connection._handle_dbapi_exception(
        942             err, None, None, dbapi_cursor, result.context
        943         )
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
       1993                 util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
       1994             elif should_wrap:
    -> 1995                 util.raise_(
       1996                     sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
       1997                 )
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
        205 
        206         try:
    --> 207             raise exception
        208         finally:
        209             # credit to
    
    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\cursor.py in fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor)
        975     def fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor):
        976         try:
    --> 977             rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
        978             result._soft_close()
        979             return rows
    
    src\pymssql\_pymssql.pyx in pymssql._pymssql.Cursor.fetchall()
    
    OperationalError: (pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError) (8134, b'Divide by zero error encountered.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n')
    (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

My script is as follows:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                                         "SERVER=xxx;"
                                         "DATABASE=xxx;"
                                         "UID=xxx;"
                                         "PWD=xxx")
    engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://xxx:xxx/xxx')


fd = open('RSCV_AÑO_MES (OK).sql', 'r')
sqlFile = fd.read()
fd.close()

DF = pd.read_sql_query(sqlFile,engine)
```

sql file has the same query that works fine in sqlserver...What am I doing wrong? the divided zero problem is alreay solved via NULLIF. I don´t understand...Thanks!

Comment: Rather than sum(NULLIF (unidades_vendidas,0))  ... your denominator would still be zero ... you want to wrap the sum() in the nullif()  like so ... nullif( sum(unidades_vendidas),0)

Comment: Good use of whitespace and formatting wouldn't go amiss. By the way, `YEARMONTH_DATE like (select concat(` is just horrible as it cannot use indexes, instead use something like `YEARMONTH_DATE >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) AND YEARMONTH_DATE < DATEADD(month, 1, DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1))`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! but YEARMONTH_DATE is an integer